# Firebase functions (putData / putFile) does not execute

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("test11.png")
let uploadTask = ref.putData(image.pngData()!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        print("metadata")
        return
    }
    print(metadata.size)
}
```

The above code worked for me once, and I managed to upload one image. When I re-started my application and wanted to test it again; the code will not upload the image to firebase storage.

I do not get any errors, but the image does not appear on firebase storage when I open it in the browser.

When I set a break point on this line
`let uploadTask = ref.putData(image.pngData()!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in`

I hope I am being clear with my problem and ask if some things are not clear enough.

---

---

UPDATE:
Apparently, the code if functional and works but it takes more than a minute to upload a 10 mb picture which is why I thought the code was broken. 
Mystery solved.

Comment: Instead of showing three samples from various sources, pick the one that is most likely to work with the version of Firebase you're using. If you're using the latest SDK, the documentation would be a great source for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files. If that doesn't work for you, show the exact code and the problem you have. "it doesn't work" is not enough there. If there is a crash: what's the error message and the stack trace? If there's no crash: what specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as stated above, I have tried all those samples including the ones from the documentation and they all have the same result. I also stated that the problem is not a crash, it just won't execute the completion block in the putData/putFile method. I was expecting it do execute the completion code.

Comment: The documentation for this task is extraordinary clear; it shows how up upload a file, and get it's URL Path. From there, simply need to save the URL in Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore. The code in the question does not match what is shown in the docs so this `let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child(key!)` is very unclear. There could be a number of reasons it's failing. I would suggest copy and pasting the code from the documentation into your app, adjust the vars for your use case and run it. If it doesn't work at that point, update the question and we will take a look.

Comment: @Jay The first thing I tried is the code in the documentation. I changed the variables and made it fit my project. It still won't execute the completion block in the putData function.  This line `let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child(key!)` (my code) = `let riversRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")
` (code from documentation)

Comment: Right. Those two pieces of code produce different results. The issue is the code in the question does not match the code in the guide. More importantly, there's no code in the question that actually stores the URL to the image in "Firebase", and without that you won't have a reference to the path to the image. I would suggest deleting what's in the question and include a code snippet of what is not working and clarify what you're asking. e.g. what does this mean `I deleted the one on firebase` the one...what? From Firebase... what? Storage? Firestore? RTDB? clarifying will help us to help you.

Comment: @Jay I will edit this question with the progress that I have.

Comment: That's better but again, it's incomplete. We don't know what *image.pngData()!* is as if image is nil, it will fail. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)